# Timer on WLS 12.1.1

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, timer, weblogic

I am using a non-persistent Timer on my Weblogic 12.1.1.
The problem is that sometimes after a system exception is raised from the callback method the timer is not executed anymore (or only once).

This problem happens even with annotated @Scheduled methods and also with programatically initialized timers (TimerService.createCalendarTimer(...))

Even on the weblogic console the timer is not displayed anymore. It's gone!

We have to restart the server to get the timer back running...

Why the timer disappears? Can anyone help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We experiencded the same behaviour with non-persistent calendar based timers on wls 12.1.1.

I think this is a bug from Oracle. The problem is already reported to oracle and is listed as [BUG 19689036](https://support.oracle.com/epmos/faces/BugDisplay?id=19689036).

**As a workaround you can use interval timer.** For us this solved our problems and still met our demands.

**We strongly advise to NOT use calendar based timers on WLS 12.1.1. Use interval-based timers instead**